# Updating Notification Email Address in Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs, automationstudio

I have around 100 automations in my business unit. I want to update the error notification email address to my email address for all of them. Is there a way to do it through API or ssjs?

Comment: Check out Rachids article here: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/12/08/subscribe-to-automation-studio-notifications-via-soap-api/amp/

Answer (score 3):

The correct payload to add your email to an automation settings is as below. This is **undocumented**, check out [this article](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/12/08/subscribe-to-automation-studio-notifications-via-soap-api/)  for more information about subscribing to Automation Studio notifications.

Now to update all of your 100 automations, you can leverage SSJS loops.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{access_token}}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options/>
         <Objects xsi:type="Automation">
            <Client>
               <ID>50000xxxx</ID>
            </Client>
            <Name>AUT_ONEOFF4</Name>
            <CustomerKey>AUT_ONEOFF4</CustomerKey>
            <Description>AUT_ONEOFF4</Description>
            <!--<CategoryID>74052</CategoryID>-->
               <Notifications>
                <Notification>
         <ChannelType>1</ChannelType>
                 <NotificationType>Complete</NotificationType>
                 <Address>rachid.mamai@xxx.com</Address>
                </Notification>
               </Notifications>
            <AutomationType>scheduled</AutomationType>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: It simply throws bad request for the payload, can you post your return soap response here? Surprisingly copy and pasting your envelope and hitting the send button throws 200 OK response.

Comment: Are you replacing all the variables in the payload? {{access_token}}, <ID>50000xxxx</ID>,

Comment: Yes, sir. I see that there isn't any notification node, neither in Automation or AutomationNotification. Also FYI tried to update the Automation (like name, description) on Automation object via WsProxy - which didn't work. Where it worked with Program object - But that made my automation to disappear in Automation Studio. How did I know it worked with Program object? When I retrieved the list of automations - It came up with updated name but not found in Automation Studio channel.

Comment: Normally, your automation will be in "My automations" folder. Try giving it a name like AAA so you can find it in the top of the "last modified" list.

Comment: Nope, It's not. Also I wonder how you can sort based on "last modified". Are you using any special version of ET :p, Please post your SOAP response of what you said It worked, That will really save my time If it's a working one.

Comment: Is this simply creating an automation?  Or is it updating an automation?